# Unable to connect to my newly created postgresql server in Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, firewall, azure-database-postgresql

After creating a new server in the Azure Database for PostgreSQL service, I get the following error when trying to connect to it. The server has been created since I see a notification on the Azure portal to the effect and can also view the server details on the Azure portal.

psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "`<ipv4 address>`", user "cloudsa", database "postgres",

Am I missing any steps in making my postgres server accessible to my client (pgadmin/psql)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common reason for getting this error right after creating a new postgresql server in Azure is not setting up firewall rules correctly so your app/client has access to the newly created server. Read more about [firewall settings in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-firewall-rules) and use either the [portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-firewall-using-cli) to manage firewall rules for your newly created postgres server. Once you have setup firewall rules correctly, you should be able to connect to the server.